# Altering the position of an article in Joomla 1

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am currently updating a web page for a company who are still using the very old Joomla 1. When creating a new menu item, I have found that an article is needed in order to create the page.

My problem is the fact that there is no option to alter the location on the page of the article. For modules, this is not a problem as there is an option which can be used to choose the specific location. For articles there is no such option, which has been of grave annoyance as they simply crop up here, there and everywhere!

If it is of any assistance the theme which is being used is contained here: http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=versatility4

Regards,

Chri3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this has changed in any version of Joomla, but it has been so long since I have looked at a Joomla 1 installation, I could be way off. Additionally, I dont have one to look at for reference.

So here goes my scientific wild &^#%! guess. When you create a menu from the menu manager in Joomla, you have to select a "menu item type". This could be a single article layout, category layout, blog layout, or link to another installed component, ect... I think its one of the first options in the menu item manager.

Then once you select "single article" there should be a dialog box that allows you to select or manually enter the article you would like to display for that menu item. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct. The location of anything being linked to in a menu item is always going to be in the component location, which by its nature does not have multiple positions. It IS a position itself which the entire template is built around.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your templates index.php file and look for the following code...

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

This is the call to the "main component" in your case would be the content component. You can move this anywhere within index.php and your article will display there